# implementing a CA and a CSP

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, audit, cloud-computing

We are in the process of implementing a CA and a CSP for our organization. I came across these issues while implementing.

- Can the CA and CSP be owned by the same party? Will there be a conflict of interest in this scenario?
- Can a CSP function without a CA? If so what are the repercussions?
- Are there any guidelines and best practices to be followed when implementing a CA and a CSP?
- If the CA and the CSP are hosted in a public cloud how does the audit happens?
- What are the recommended products for a CA and a CSP?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by csp? I'm only familiar with the tla being applied to cryptographic service provider - a mswindows dll, but that makes no sense in the context of your question.

Comment: CSP means Certificate Service Provider